# Magento 2 Custom Cli comand Area not set

Tags: magento2, php, module, custom, cli

I am geting this error comand "[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Area code is not set
"

this is my code which I want to add a product. Tip if a comment " $product->save();" I am not getinng erros and I can see my output.

My code:

```
<?php


namespace Bachus\BackgroundImport\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Importpr extends Command
{

    const NAME_ARGUMENT = "name";
    const NAME_OPTION = "option";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
) {
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); // or 'adminhtml', depending on your needs
}
     */ 
    protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    ) { 
        $name = $input->getArgument(self::NAME_ARGUMENT);
        $option = $input->getOption(self::NAME_OPTION);
       // parent::__construct();

   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
   $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
 $product->setSku($name); // Set your sku here
  $product->setName('Sample Simple Product'); // Name of Product
  $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
  $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
  $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
  $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
  $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
  $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
  $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
  $product->setStockData(
                        array(
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                            'manage_stock' => 1,
                            'is_in_stock' => 1,
                            'qty' => 999999999
                        )
                    );
$product->save();
/*  */

    $output->writeln("Product added sku " . $name);



    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName("bachus_cli:importpr");
        $this->setDescription("imports-produts");
        $this->setDefinition([
            new InputArgument(self::NAME_ARGUMENT, InputArgument::OPTIONAL, "Name"),
            new InputOption(self::NAME_OPTION, "-a", InputOption::VALUE_NONE, "Option functionality")
        ]);
        parent::configure();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have set `areacode` in your construct. Why did you comment that code? please uncomment it and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

protected $_appState;


public function __construct(
    ...
    State $appState
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_appState = $appState;
    ....
}
```

Now in your code set area which want (i.e frontend or adminhtml) for example,

```
  $this->_appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
```